# Create Active Model datetime with Epoch Timestamps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, activerecord, epoch

I have a mobile application that can create events by sending a Post request to our Rails application using the standard routing for a `SimpleEvent` model. The important pieces of the model look like so in the schema:

```
create_table "simple_events", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "start_date",   null: false
    t.datetime "end_date",     null: false
end
```

It is simplest for the app to send up the float values to indicate time because that is how they are stored in locally. However, when I try to create a `SimpleEvent` in the rails console using an epoch timestamp with the following line:

```
SimpleEvent.create("start_date"=> 1406815132.0, "end_date"=> 1406815132.0)
```

I get this error:

```
ArgumentError: argument out of range
    from /Users/ataylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:289:in `initialize'
    from /Users/ataylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:289:in `new'
    from /Users/ataylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:289:in `parse'
    from /Users/ataylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/zones.rb:9:in `in_time_zone'
    from /Users/ataylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/time_zone_conversion.rb:37:in `start_date='
    from /Users/ataylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:45:in `public_send'
    from /Users/ataylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:45:in `_assign_attribute'
    from /Users/ataylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:32:in `block in assign_attributes'
    from /Users/ataylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:26:in `each'
    from /Users/ataylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:26:in `assign_attributes'
    from /Users/ataylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/core.rb:455:in `init_attributes'
    from /Users/ataylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/core.rb:198:in `initialize'
    from /Users/ataylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:30:in `new'
    from /Users/ataylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:30:in `new'
    from /Users/ataylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:33:in `create'
    from (irb):71
    from /Users/ataylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /Users/ataylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/ataylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
    from /Users/ataylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/ataylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'2.1.1 :072 >
```

I tried digging around in the rails source code for a possible explanation but didn't have much luck. What can I do to allow DateTimes to be created from a timestamp in a model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still want to be able to use `start_date` and `end_date` with normal time objects or strings, I would create a couple of new methods that set start_date/end_date from timestrings:

```
class SimpleEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
  def start_ts=(ts)
    write_attribute :start_date, DateTime.strptime(ts.to_s, '%s')
  end

  def end_ts=(ts)
    write_attribute :end_date, DateTime.strptime(ts.to_s, '%s')
  end
end
```

To use them:

```
SimpleEvent.create("start_ts"=>"1406815132.0", "end_ts"=>"1406815132.0")
```

Now when you create a SimpleEvent using the start_ts/end_ts methods, it will parse the timestamps and set the start_date/end_date appropriately.

Comment: I really like this solution, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working for me. I added `attr_accessor :start_ts` and `attr_accessor :end_ts` to get rid of this error: `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: start_ts` but it still does not save, instead performing a rollback and the resulting SimpleEvent object has nil for the `start_date` and `end_date` attributes. Am I missing anything?

Comment: My apologies, I forgot to add `=` to the method names.  I'm updating my answer with the correct method names.

Comment: Thank you! That's perfect. The times had to be sent in number format, not as strings as in my original question which I will update, and I didn't need the `attr_accessor` lines at all, consistent with your answer.

Comment: @kujenga, I will update my answer to handle `ts` as a string, integer, or float.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest saving the datetime by adding an extra function to convert it to datetime and store.

```
class SimpleEvent < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.save_time start_time, end_time
      self.create(start_time: Time.at(start_time).to_datetime, end_time: Time.at(end_time).to_datetime
  end
end
```

and we care write a function in the model itself so that we can read the data as epoch time itself.

```
class SimpleEvent < ActiveRecord::Base

   def started_at
      self.start_time.to_i
   end

   def end_at
      self.end_time.to_i
   end
end
```